# Android Studio does not show my device while running the project

Tags: android, android-studio

When i tried to run my project in android studio it does not show any device

But i had correctly installed the adb interface driver and it also show in my device manager(Android Device -> Android Composite ADB Interface ).

My device is LAVA iris X1 (kitkat 4.4.2)

1. Usb debugging was on
2. usb connection was switched to  PTP (Camera)

I had also tried certain posts but non of them works

Please provide a helpful solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what if you run the `adb wait-for-device` or `adb devices` from terminal? do you see your device ther?

Answer (score 0):

launch 2 devices at the same time, sometimes the firts device launched is not showing probably for some bug but the second is recognized

Comment: thanks for advice but unfortunately it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Did you download the proper drivers for your device? I also find it useful to have the device dialog come up. If you go to Run Configurations you can select an option which will show the device chooser every time. Sometimes I have to plug and unplug my phone once or twice for it to be recognized. This screens help me debug this potential issue. Other then that check the drivers for the device if on Windows.